# Change view in browser settings in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I have installed the view in browser plugin in Sublime text 2. It opens in firefox by default and I'd like to change this to google chrome.

I've opened the settings file and I am unsure which part to edit to change this, so if someone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

http://postimg.org/image/jr0f1xzgp/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser/wiki/Configuring-Browsers?

It states there that:

> For illustration purposes let's say you want your default browser to
>   be Google Chrome. To do this populate this [new] settings file with the
>   following.
>
> {    "selectedBrowser": "chrome" }
>
> After you save this file you can
>   test your new settings file by pressing CTRL + ALT + V and you should
>   see your new settings file open in Google Chrome, assuming you have it
>   installed of course.